# How can i load two level routing in High Server Http Akka using Java?

Tags: java, akka, akka-http

I'm trying to work with `akka Http` with `Java`.

I would like to load a route that look like this :
`hello/world`

On my `HttpApp`, I tried:

```
return route(
                path("hello/world", () ->
                        get(() ->
                                complete("<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>")
                        )
                );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, as per the [docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/java/http/routing-dsl/directives/path-directives/path.html#path).

```
import static akka.http.javadsl.server.PathMatchers.*;

return route(
  path(segment("hello").slash(segment("world")), () ->
    get(() ->
     complete("<h1>Say hello to akka-http</h1>")
    )
);
```

Comment: I try it, but doesn't works.
I got the following errors:

- Cannot resolve method segment(java.lang.String)
- Cannot resolve method slash(java.lang.String)

In facts, Intellij IDEA autocomplete doens't works with segment or slash functions.

Comment: You're probably missing an import. I have added it to the answer.